# "Notice: Undefined index..." error on web server but works perfectly on localhost

Tags: php, session, undefined-index

I only have two files, but get `Notice: Undefined index...` error with the session when running on web server, but it works perfectly on localhost

login.php:

```
    <?php 
    session_start(); 
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;

    <form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" >
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>

    <?php
    $pw = (isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : null);
    $sb = (isset($_POST['submit']) ? $_POST['submit'] : null);

    if($pw == "8000"){
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 'green';
    }

    if($pw != "8000" && $sb != null){
    echo '<div class="warning">Password Incorrect !!</div>';
    exit;
    }
```

index.php:

```
    <?php
    session_start(); 
    if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in']!= 'green')
    {  
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
    }
    include 'db.php';
```

After the PHP part, HTML code runs without having any whitespace.

When I try to access the index.php file before starting a session, the webpage shows this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: logged_in in
>   /bla/bla/bla/bla/public_html/index.php on line 3

Though this error is not present on localhost.

Comment: yeah....but i need this exact feature. not a bit more than this and also not a less than this

Comment: Your code explicitly says ***"if `$_SESSION['logged_in']` is NOT set***, and then you're accessing `$_SESSION['logged_in']`. Of course it will throw that error. You have the condition backwards. The difference between your local and production server is merely the configured error reporting level.

Comment: Seems to me like this code would result in an infinite loop (if it weren't for the error).  You're redirecting _everything_ from login.php to index.php before you do _anything_.  Don't try breaking up your code for posting here, please post _exactly_ what your code is.

Comment: Maybe I edited it wrong, but this seems like an infinite loop

Comment: As @deceze said your logic is wrong on the line that reads `if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in']!= 'green')`. With the && in there you will get that error since you're telling PHP to always check to see if logged_in is green even if it isn't set.

Comment: yeah...it is infinite loop!!! would you please correct me by writing the codes?

Comment: @james yes it is, but only after the notice is resolved or `error reporting` is disabled :P

Comment: please guys answer this question and show me the codes by a right way to do this. I would be grateful to you. :D

Comment: Surely you just need to remove `header("Location: index.php"); exit;` from your login.php?

Comment: i am still facing the same error buddy... :( 
"Undefined index: logged_in in /bla/bla/bla/bla/public_html/index.php on line 3"

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` condition is not correct you need to do this like

first you should check if array key exist then you should compare it with something.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) || $_SESSION['logged_in']!= 'green')
{  
header('Location: login.php');
exit;
}
```

**UPDATE :**
Remove this

```
header("Location: index.php");
exit;
```

And add this to your login page

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in']== 'green')
{  
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
```

This should help you.

Comment: Thank you DEarTh for your kind help. the undefined index problem is now solved. but the login page does not redirect to the index page when i remove the header from the login page. Again if i keep the header in login page then infinite loop occurs

Comment: please help me once more to solve this infinite loop or no redirect issue

Answer (score 0):

I normally don't answer questions like this as with a little trial and error you could have solved it :) But hopefully this will show you a good beginner path to go down for future coding (then you move on to classes and better things).

With this code you separate all the things into new files or functions. This makes your code tidy, easy to read, easy to maintain, and moreso easy to reuse the same things in other places of your codebase.

Such as you might need to set the sessions in some place other than `login.php`. This approach is already used below, as the `isLoggedIn()` function is used in `login.php` and `index.php`.

E.g. If your login value needs to ever change (such as "green" to "red") then you change the value in `getSessionSecurityValue()` and `isLoggedIn()` and `setLoginSession()` functions are auto changed.

**NOTE:** I have not tested this code, but should work as long as you put the things in files as below.

> **login.php:**

```
require_once 'initialise.php';
require_once 'isLoggedIn.php';
require_once 'isPasswordValid.php';
require_once 'setLoginSession.php';

// If logged in no need to do the form thing
if (isLoggedIn() === true) {
    // Redirect to index
    // Or echo message "already logged in" and exit so not to show the login form
}

// Initialise vars
$errorMessage = null;
$postPassword = null;

// If form submitted
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $postPassword = $_POST['password'];
    $passwordValid = isPasswordValid($postPassword);

    // Password is valid, set their session and send them to index page
    if ($passwordValid === true) {
        setLoginSession();
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
    }

    // Password not valid (would have redirected above otherwise)
    $errorMessage = '<div class="warning">Password Incorrect !!</div>';
}

// If we have an error message show it
if ($errorMessage !== null) {
    echo $errorMessage;
}

?>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>
```

> **index.php:**

```
require_once 'initialise.php';
require_once 'isLoggedIn.php';

// If not logged in send to login page
if (isLoggedIn() === false) {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
}

// They're logged in, good to go...
include 'db.php';
```

> **isPasswordValid.php:**

```
/**
 * Check the entered password.
 *
 * @param string $password
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function isPasswordValid($password)
{
    return $password == '8000' ? true : false;
}
```

> **isLoggedIn.php:**

```
require_once 'getSessionSecurityValue.php';

/**
 * Check if the user is logged in.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function isLoggedIn()
{
    return (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] == getSessionSecurityValue())
        ? true
        : false;
}
```

> **initialise.php:**

```
/** Add startup and other shared things in here that are relevant to some initialisation */

// Start session if not already started
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

> **setLoginSession.php:**

```
require_once 'getSessionSecurityValue.php';

/**
 * Sets the session to show user is logged in.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function setLoginSession()
{
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = getSessionSecurityValue();
}
```

> **getSessionSecurityValue.php:**

```
/**
 * Gets the "security" value used in the login session.
 *
 * @return string
 */
function getSessionSecurityValue()
{
    return 'green';
}
```

Comment: No problem. glad to help